# Change Fluentui theme

Tags: c#, user-interface, blazor, blazor-webassembly, fluent-ui

I am using a blazor project and I want to change the colors by default.

```
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- If you add any scoped CSS files, uncomment the following to load them-->
<link href="Officiel.BackOffice.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I dont know how, but these two lines in the index.html file are the ones that make the .css files work but there is a predifined styles such as the blue color for the header I am enable to change it even in my .css file. Here is my code
Client.razor file
`<FluentHeader> <div class="header">Clients list</div> </FluentHeader>`

client.razor.css file
`.header { background-color: #9EA3B0; padding: 30px; text-align: center; font-size: 35px; }`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your issue is, maybe this link helps [https://www.fluentui-blazor.net/DesignTheme].